# MS DOS Command Prompt - Providing several input file names in one command

Tags: command-prompt, dos

Probably basic question, but either I cannot find the answer, or I don't know what words to use to search for them.

I have a command line program which accepts three file names after the .exe has been called. I also have a program which is designed to run this program and test it's outputs automatically. So the situation is that I'm running one program and need to give it instructions on how to run the other. Through the constraints of the program I need to provide a one-line command that will execute the model.
My question is: How in MS DOS command prompt can I both 1)  execute the program and 2) provide the three known file names all in one command.

Thanks!

Further Context:
These two programs are not written by me, rather they are two command-line executables. The "first" program is a simple model which runs through the command prompt. The second is a calibration program which needs to run the model (perhaps hundreds of times) to calibrate certain input parameters. Thus I need to tell the calibration program how to run the model. However I need to do that in one line, or a batch file.

Comment: Your second program - the one that should run the first program - in what is it written?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make use of command-line arguments. This is not clear though, how would you normally provide instructions to the program (not through the command line)?

Comment: zmbq: Both programs are provided to me as executable, the second one I'm not sure of, but I know the first is written in FORTRAN
lc: Both programs are command-line programs. If I was running the first program only (not automated by the second) then the information (in this case, file names) are provided as user-input directly from the command prompt. i.e. when I (or the automation program) call the first program from it's .exe it executes, then displays a command "enter control file name" in the command line. The user then inputs the specified file name. This is repeated three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are after what is calling "piping." The output of one program is feed to the input of another. This is expressed in one command line.

For example, `dir` produces a sequence of lines and `sort` reads lines, sorts them and writes them out. So,

`dir | sort`

You can pipe as many programs together as you like and pass any arguments they need.

`dir | find "2013" | sort`

EDIT:
Update based on your comments.

If the second program just reads the output of the first then you can do it like this.

`first <filelist.txt | second`

where filelist.txt is a text file with the three responses required by the `first` program.
The `<` means that `first` will not read what is typed but instead read from the file.

Comment: Excellent! I was trying in the past to list the three files like such:
first < 1.txt < 2.txt < 3.txt
and it wouldn't work. However this file list idea works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
C:\>program.exe "file1" "file2" "file3"
```

Comment: for some reason it will still not pass the file names on. Entering such a line, the program still halts to wait for input at the first prompt

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide source since both of these programs are provided to me as executables, I'll try to clarify my post with screen captures and more description above.